i3 freezes when launching an Nvidia Accelerated Application on Nvidia Optimus
I am using i3 on a laptop with an rtx 3060 and an Intel Tigerlake GPU. The Nvidia GPU uses driver 550.67 and is for the most part working. DRM is not enabled (system refuses to boot to GUI if it is). I mostly use prime-run to run GPU accelerated applications. But there's a problem. Whenever I launch one of these (a game for example), the system often freezes. The only way to fix that is hitting ctrl-alt-f2 and switching back to desktop. Sometimes applications like discord also crash when I do this. Sometimes the freezes take a few seconds. It also happens when shutting down an application. The Xorg log doesn't show any results. THis never happens when I use the intel GPU.
My question is, how do I debug this? Are there any logs of the nvidia driver itself?
